# Round Function return only two decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below syntax and want to return only two decimal places. Can this be done with the Round Function? If so, how?

```
 SELECT             
 CONVERT(DECIMAL,SUM(colors))/CONVERT(DECIMAL,COUNT(DISTINCTid) AVG_CONTACTS_VISITS_PER_MONTH
 from a
```

Comment: Add one example and its expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the second argument for [`ROUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) is the length. So your query would look like this:

```
SELECT          
    ROUND( CONVERT(DECIMAL,SUM(colors))/CONVERT(DECIMAL,COUNT(DISTINCTid)), 2) AS AVG_CONTACTS_VISITS_PER_MONTH
from a
```

Comment: I'm getting "Round Function requires 2 to 3 arguments"

Comment: SOMETHING LIKET HIS... ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL,SUM(COLORS))/CONVERT(DECIMAL,COUNT(DISTINCT ID)),2,2) AS AVG_TOTAL_CONTACT_PER_MONTH